# Eclipse Mars - one specific file will not open in compare editor?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, svn, compare, subclipse

All of the sudden last week, a single javascript file will no longer open in the compare editor.

- I am running the latest Mars Eclipse
- I am running the latest Subclipse
- I sync with the repo, and see the changed file
- When I double click or choose to compare, I either see a blank white page with "Initializing..." or a blank gray page
- it is ONLY with one specific text .js file ... all other files in the project, and other projects diff just fine.
- the file is 37,880 bytes
- I have deleted the subversion settings files, and they were recreated
- I have checked the preferences and ignore whitespace

It is only this ONE file ... and it is a main file of a node.js project.  It used to diff just fine, and all of the sudden last week this one file will no longer diff and throws this exception.

When I look in the log, I see the following exception:

> !ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2016-04-14 12:38:08.535
>   !MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
>   !STACK 0
>   org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Failed to execute runnable (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4491)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4406)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:138)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4155)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3772)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1127)
>       at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1018)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:694)
>       at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:606)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:139)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
>       at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.dom.ASTNode.setSourceRange(ASTNode.java:2490)
>       at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.dom.ASTConverter.convertToVariableDeclarationStatement(ASTConverter.java:2696)
>       at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.dom.ASTConverter.checkAndAddMultipleLocalDeclaration(ASTConverter.java:319)
>       at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.dom.ASTConverter.convert(ASTConverter.java:436)
>       at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.dom.ASTConverter.convert(ASTConverter.java:1175)
>       at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.dom.JavaScriptUnitResolver.convert(JavaScriptUnitResolver.java:262)
>       at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.dom.ASTParser.internalCreateAST(ASTParser.java:887)
>       at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.dom.ASTParser.createAST(ASTParser.java:647)
>       at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.ui.compare.JavaStructureCreator.createStructureComparator(JavaStructureCreator.java:284)
>       at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.ui.compare.JavaStructureCreator.createStructureComparator(JavaStructureCreator.java:243)
>       at org.eclipse.compare.structuremergeviewer.StructureCreator.internalCreateStructure(StructureCreator.java:121)
>       at org.eclipse.compare.structuremergeviewer.StructureCreator.access$0(StructureCreator.java:109)
>       at org.eclipse.compare.structuremergeviewer.StructureCreator$1.run(StructureCreator.java:96)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
>       at org.eclipse.compare.internal.Utilities.runInUIThread(Utilities.java:859)
>       at org.eclipse.compare.structuremergeviewer.StructureCreator.createStructure(StructureCreator.java:102)
>       at org.eclipse.compare.structuremergeviewer.StructureDiffViewer$StructureInfo.createStructure(StructureDiffViewer.java:155)
>       at org.eclipse.compare.structuremergeviewer.StructureDiffViewer$StructureInfo.refresh(StructureDiffViewer.java:133)
>       at org.eclipse.compare.structuremergeviewer.StructureDiffViewer$StructureInfo.setInput(StructureDiffViewer.java:104)
>       at org.eclipse.compare.structuremergeviewer.StructureDiffViewer.compareInputChanged(StructureDiffViewer.java:342)
>       at org.eclipse.compare.structuremergeviewer.StructureDiffViewer$2.run(StructureDiffViewer.java:74)
>       at org.eclipse.compare.structuremergeviewer.StructureDiffViewer$6.run(StructureDiffViewer.java:322)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
>       at org.eclipse.compare.structuremergeviewer.StructureDiffViewer.compareInputChanged(StructureDiffViewer.java:319)
>       at org.eclipse.compare.structuremergeviewer.StructureDiffViewer.compareInputChanged(StructureDiffViewer.java:307)
>       at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.ui.compare.JavaStructureDiffViewer.compareInputChanged(JavaStructureDiffViewer.java:143)
>       at org.eclipse.compare.structuremergeviewer.StructureDiffViewer.inputChanged(StructureDiffViewer.java:278)
>       at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ContentViewer.setInput(ContentViewer.java:292)
>       at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.setInput(StructuredViewer.java:1701)
>       at org.eclipse.compare.CompareViewerSwitchingPane.setInput(CompareViewerSwitchingPane.java:277)
>       at org.eclipse.compare.internal.CompareStructureViewerSwitchingPane.setInput(CompareStructureViewerSwitchingPane.java:132)
>       at org.eclipse.compare.CompareEditorInput.feedInput(CompareEditorInput.java:747)
>       at org.eclipse.compare.CompareEditorInput.createContents(CompareEditorInput.java:555)
>       at org.eclipse.compare.internal.CompareEditor.createCompareControl(CompareEditor.java:462)
>       at org.eclipse.compare.internal.CompareEditor.access$6(CompareEditor.java:422)
>       at org.eclipse.compare.internal.CompareEditor$3.run(CompareEditor.java:378)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UILockListener.doPendingWork(UILockListener.java:162)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer$3.run(UISynchronizer.java:154)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
>       ... 23 more

Answer (score 17):

I don't have a solution, but I ran into the same problem and found a workaround. I switched off "Open structure compare automatically" in the eclipse preferences under "General" -> "Compare/Patch". Then I was able open the file in the compare editor.

Comment: worked for me, i dont understand what the thing does anyways, in the eclipse docs it just says "Open structure compare automatically" -> "Makes an additional information area visible which shows differences in the underlying structure of the resources being compared. This information may not be available for all comparisons."

Answer (score 2):

This looks like Eclipse bug [390913](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=390913) which has been open for some time but doesn't seem to have made any progress.

Comment: yep ... and like some of that comments on that bug I'm at a loss of what exactly is in the text of this file that is causing the problem.  If I had some idea I would edit the file and remove the offending content ... but of course it's also silly that Eclipse is throwing the exception in the first place.   :-/